# Fetch a Filenet document with Properties

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I'm trying to do a test program deal with Filenet Documents. I know how to get a document Instance with `Object Id` or `path` like ,

```
doc  =  Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os,ID,null);
doc  =  Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os,path,null);
```

but I like to add more finding options so I can fetch, 
Document with name or a custom property . I am trying out this search as a approach to that:

```
String mySQLString = "SELECT * FROM DEMO WHERE DocumentTitle LIKE '"+prp+"'";
    SearchSQL sqlObject = new SearchSQL();
    sqlObject.setQueryString(mySQLString);

   // System.out.println(mySQLString);
    SearchScope searchScope = new SearchScope(os);
    RepositoryRowSet rowSet = searchScope.fetchRows(sqlObject, null, null, new Boolean(true));
    Iterator ppg = rowSet.iterator();

    if (ppg.hasNext()) {

            RepositoryRow rr = (RepositoryRow) ppg.next();
            System.err.println(rr.getProperties());
            Properties properties = rr.getProperties();

            String ID = properties.getStringValue("ID");
            System.out.println(ID);

    doc  =  Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os,ID,null);
```

But ID is not a Document property , it's a System property. How can I get the document? How can I get the `path` or `id` with a Search and fetch this document ? Is there a fast way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few little changes I have made it work. Following is the code

```
    String mySQLString = "SELECT ID FROM Document WHERE DocumentTitle LIKE '"+prp+"'";
    SearchSQL sqlObject = new SearchSQL();
    sqlObject.setQueryString(mySQLString);

    SearchScope searchScope = new SearchScope(os);
    RepositoryRowSet rowSet = searchScope.fetchRows(sqlObject, null, null, new Boolean(true));
    Iterator ppg = rowSet.iterator();

    if (ppg.hasNext()) {

            RepositoryRow rr = (RepositoryRow) ppg.next();
            System.err.println(rr.getProperties());
            Properties properties = rr.getProperties();

            String ID = properties.getIdValue("ID").toString();
            System.out.println(ID);                

            doc  =  Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os,ID,null);

    }
```

now with few changes this can be use to get any document with property.

Comment: note that there's also the searchScope.fetchObjects, that immediately gives you the Document object. Combined it with "select *" to have the document populated with it's properties. This reduces the need for an additional fetchInstance (roundtrip)

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate through all the documents. Take a look at this:

```
public void iterateThruAllDocs(ObjectStore os, String foldername) {
    Folder folder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(os, foldername, null);
    Document doc = Factory.Document.getInstance(os, null, foldername);

    DocumentSet docset = folder.get_ContainedDocuments();
    Iterator<DocumentSet> docitr = docset.iterator();

    while (docitr.hasNext()) {

        doc = (Document) docitr.next();
        String mydocid = doc.get_Id().toString();
        Document mydoc = Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os, mydocid, null);
        AccessPermissionList apl = mydoc.get_Permissions();
        Iterator ite = apl.iterator();
        while (ite.hasNext()) {
            Properties documentProperties = doc.getProperties();
            String DateCreated = documentProperties.getDateTimeValue("DateCreated").toString();
            String DateLastModified = documentProperties.getDateTimeValue("DateLastModified").toString();
            Permission permission = (Permission) ite.next();
            String docTitle = doc.getProperties().getStringValue("DocumentTitle");
            System.out.println("Document Title for document with DocumentID \"" + mydoc.get_Id() + "\" is \"" + docTitle + "\"");
            //String someprop = documentProperties.getStringValue("someprop");
            System.out.println("Document was Created on  :: " + DateCreated);
            System.out.println("Document was Last Modified on :: " + DateLastModified);
            System.out.println("Grantee Name :: " + permission.get_GranteeName());
            //if (permission.get_GranteeName().equals(groupname/username)) {
            //permission.set_GranteeName("groupname/username");
            //  System.out.println("Security REMOVED for document....");
            //mydoc.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
            // Go Nuts on Documents Here......
            break;
        }
    }
}
```